# Sie traf ihn, als sie am Ufer entlang spazieren ging

Tags: sentence-structure

Isn't *spazierengehen* a separable verb? Why in this dependent clause in this example the verb is separated? Should not it be:

> "Sie traf ihn, als sie am Ufer entlang spazierenging."

as a one word?

Comment: Both is possible. There are a lot of separable verbs which come in both flavours, especially after the botched 1996 writing reform.

Comment: @Janka You are right, after the reform there are in deed a lot of verbs with both variants - but that is **not** right for this verb. According to [canoo.net](http://www.canoo.net/services/Controller?input=spazieren+gehen&dispatch=spelling) only "spazieren gehen" (Getrenntschreibung) is correct for this verb!

Comment: I would also like to emphasize, like IQV, that it is **not correct** to write *spazierengehen* as a verb. It does not suffice the criteria of a separable verb, but is a fixed expression using two verbs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Übliche Sichtweise (Verb + Verb)

Gemäß der aktualisierten Fassung des [amtlichen Regelwerks](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2017.pdf) gilt – ich zitiere –:

> **§ 34**
>
> (4) Verbindungen mit einem verbalen ersten Bestandteil.
>
> Verbindungen aus zwei Verben werden getrennt geschrieben, zum Beispiel:
>   
>   *laufen lernen, arbeiten kommen, baden gehen, lesen üben*

Daher muss es, selbst zu meinem Erstaunen, normalerweise heißen:

> *spazieren gehen*

#### Alternative Sichtweise (Substantiv + Verb)

Nun kann man Verben aber auch substantivieren:

> (das) Laufen, (das) Arbeiten, (das) Lesen, (das) Spazieren

Das Ergebnis sind *echte* Substantive (siehe Zusatz unten). Nun gibt es auch eine Regel für Zusammensetzungen mit Substantiven als ersten Bestandteil, und die besagt:

> **§ 34**
>
> (3) Zusammensetzungen mit einem substantivischen ersten Bestandteil.
>
> Dabei handelt es sich um folgende Fälle, bei denen die ersten Bestandteile die Eigenschaften selbständiger Substantive weitgehend verloren haben:
>   
>   *eislaufen, kopfstehen, leidtun, nottun, standhalten, stattfinden, stattgeben,
>   statthaben, teilhaben, teilnehmen, wundernehmen*

Je nach Kontext könnte man bei

> spazierengehen

also argumentieren, dass man das Substantiv *(das) Spazieren* und das Verb *gehen* gemäß Regel §34(3) zusammengeschrieben habe. Dabei ist es völlig egal, ob *(das) Spazieren* eine Substantivierung des Verbs *spazieren* ist. Die Eigenschaft, ein Substantiv zu sein, ist alles, was als Kriterium gefordert wird.

---

<sub>**Zusatz:**</sub>

<sub>Aufgrund einiger zweifelnder Kommentatoren, möchte ich hier noch einige Quellen zitieren, die belegen sollen, dass das Ergebnis einer Substantivierung tatsächlich ein Substantiv ist.</sub>

<sub>Bei [Wikipedia (Substantivierung)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung) findet man</sub>

> <sub>**Die Substantivierung [...] ist die Bildung eines Substantivs** aus einer anderen Wortart, vor allem aus Verben und Adjektiven.</sub>

<sub>Weiter unten ([Wikipedia (Substantivierung#Allgemeines)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung#Allgemeines)) steht sogar explizit:</sub>

> <sub>Bei der Substantivierung kann die Form des Wortes geändert werden (Derivation, etwa durch Präfixe oder Suffixe), oder sie kann erhalten bleiben (**Konversion**). **Substantivierung ändert die Wortart.** So können neue Wörter erzeugt werden.</sub>

<sub>Der Wortartenwechsel ist also eine **Konversion**. Schaut man bei [Wikipedia (Konversion#Syntaktische_Konversion)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konversion_(Linguistik)#Syntaktische_Konversion) nach, findet man als Beispiel</sub>

> <sub>**Verb im Infinitiv → Substantiv**</sub>
>
> <sub>leben – (das) Leben</sub>

<sub>Selbst bei [Wikipedia (Substantiv#Morphologische_Klassifikation)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantiv#Morphologische_Klassifikation) findet man:</sub>

> <sub>**Ein sekundäres Substantiv ist eines, das durch Ableitung, nämlich Substantivierung, gebildet ist**.</sub>

<sub>Dabei ist die Einteilung in *primäre* und *sekundäre* Substantive nur eine Morphologische Klassifikation, die nichts daran ändert, dass *sekundäre* Substantive eben Substantive sind.</sub>

<sub>Und sogar unter dem Eintrag **Substantiv** selbst findet man bei [Wikipedia (Substantiv#Durch_Ableitung_(Substantivierung))](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantiv#Durch_Ableitung_(Substantivierung)):</sub>

> <sub>**Substantive können auf der Basis von Mitgliedern jeglicher Wortart**,[13] allerdings kaum von Adverbien, **abgeleitet werden. Ist die Basis kein Substantiv, heißt der Vorgang Substantivierung** (im engeren Sinne).</sub>

<sub>sowie</sub>

> <sub>Auf syntaktischer Ebene genügt es, ein Wort mit dem definiten Artikel zu kombinieren, um es („zwangsweise“) zu substantivieren, wie in die Grünen, das Streiten, das Ich.</sub>

<sub>Wer jetzt noch behauptet, dass das aus dem Verb *spazieren* durch Substantivierung gebildete Wort *(das) Spazieren* kein Substantiv wäre, sondern immer noch ein Verb, der kann ja mal versuchen, *(das) Spazieren* zu konjugieren (das sollte bei einem Verb ja möglich sein). Geht nicht? Tja, ...</sub>

Comment: Ich halte den letzten Satz für eine etwas gewagte Argumentation. Bei allen Beispielen von § 34 (3) wird deutlich, dass es um "echte" Substantive geht und nicht um substantivierte Verben. Mit diesem Argument könnte man sonst den kompletten § 34 (4) aushebeln, weil alle Verben der Beispiele substantiviert werden können.

Comment: @IQV: Das ist doch genau der Punkt: das Ergebnis einer Substantivierung ist ein Substantiv!

Comment: Nein. Wie gesagt, ich halte diese Argumentation für seeehr konstruiert.

Comment: @IQV: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantivierung

Comment: Gängigerweise spricht man bei "(das) Spazieren" nicht von einem Substantiv. Solche substantivierten Infinitive teilen bereits nicht alle Eigenschaften von Substantiven (sie sind etwa prinzipiell nicht pluralfähig). Ganz gewiss ist das im Regelwerk auch nicht gemeint, siehe @IQV.

Comment: @johnl, haben sie den Wikipediaeintrag gelesen, oder haben Sie ihn einfach ignoriert? Oder sagen Sie gar, das der Inhalt dort nicht stimme? Haben Sie alternative Quellen? Zudem ist mir neu, dass es auf die eideutige Frage nach der Wortart _gängige_ und _nicht gängige_ Antworten gäbe. Für das Ergebnis einer Substantivierung lautet die Antwort eindeutig: Substantiv (Quelle: zum Beispiel Wikipedia).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Gewöhnlicherweise versteht man unter Substantiven eben selbständige Substantive, nicht bloße Spielarten - hier: Nominalformen - des Verbs. Vgl. nur Thielmann in Hoffmann, Hdb. dt. Wortarten, 2009, S. 806 ("... handelt es sich um einen sog. 'substantivierten Infinitiv' ... Infinitive sind **substantiv-nahe Ausdrücke**, die neutrales Genus besitzen. Sie sind mithin als _deverbale Ableitungen_ aufzufassen, die _determinationsfähig_ sind"; eigene Hervorhebung). Ich sage "gewöhnlicherweise", weil es natürlich Zusammenhänge gibt, in denen es auf die Differenzierung nicht ankommt.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Nach dieser Argumentation wären also Konstruktionen wie "Er muss noch arbeitengehen/laufengehen/lesenlernen" korrekt?

Comment: Eventuell liegt der entscheidende Teil in dieser Formulierung: "Substantivierte Wörter nehmen die Eigenschaften von Substantiven an."  Im Folgenden wird nur auf die Großschreibung und die Funktion im Satz eingegangen. Man könnte also behaupten, dass substantivierte Verben zwar die Eigenschaften von Substantiven übernehmen, aber keine Substantive *sind*, sich also nicht immer identisch verhalten, wie @johnl auch schreibt.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Was für einen Sinn hat dann §34 (4) überhaupt? Man kann jedes Verb substantivieren, also könnte man die angegebenen Beispiele *laufen lernen, arbeiten kommen, baden gehen, lesen üben* auch alle zusammen schreiben. Das wird nirgendwo erwähnt.

Comment: @RoyPJ: Der Sinn von §34(4) ist es, anzugeben, wie der Fall _Verb + Verb_ zu behandeln ist, zum Beispiel das Verb _lesen_ und das Verb _lernen_. Der Sinn von §34(3) ist es, anzugeben, wie der Fall _Substantiv + Verb_ zu behandeln ist, zum Beispiel das Substantiv _(das) Lesen_ und das Verb _lernen_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Aber da man doch jedes Verb substantivieren kann, könnte man doch jede Kombination von Verb + Verb als Substantiv + Verb auffassen, wodurch §34 (3) zum Zuge käme...

Comment: @RoyPJ: Wir reden aneinander vorbein! Es steht doch **vorher** fest, ob es eine Substantivierung (also Substantiv) oder ein Verb ist. Man kann doch nicht wahrlos jedes Verb durch die Substantivierung ersetzen.  Und erst wenn das klar ist, schaut man nach. Bei _Ich will (das) Lesen lernen_ würde man nach §34(3) _Ich will lesenlernen_ schreiben. Bei _Ich will lernen zu lesen_ würde man nach §34(4) _Ich will lesen lernen_ schreiben. Bei _(das) Spazieren gehen_ ist das sicherlich schwieriger, weil man es nicht so sagt, aber dennoch gilt die allgemeine Regel.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich verstehe dich schon, mein Punkt ist eher, dass also sowohl *lesenlernen* als auch *lesen lernen* korrekt ist, auch wenn es von unterschiedlichen Konstruktionen abgeleitet ist. Das kann ich mir einfach nicht vorstellen. Aber wir kommen hier sicher nicht durch eine Diskussion zu Klarheit, also werde ich das bei Gelegenheit weiter recherchieren :)

Comment: @RoyPJ: Genau so meine ich das. Wer _Ich will lesenlernen_ schreibt, der macht nichts falsch, sofern er _Ich wil (das) Lesen lernen_ ausdrücken möchte. So, und damit beende ich auch die Diskussion. Belege habe ich ja ausreichend angeführt ..

Comment: Auf meine Anfrage habe ich vom Leiter der Vechtaer Sprachauskunft, Prof. Jochen Bär, eine Auskunft erhalten: "[...] dass § 34 (3) nicht deverbale Substantivierungen im Blick hat, sondern primäre Substantive. Also nicht Beispiele wie lesenlernen (weil ≠ das Lesen lernen), sondern kopfstehen, teilhaben, standhalten, nottun usw. Bei verbalem Erstglied greift § 34 (4); diese Wörter werden getrennt geschrieben (laufen lernen, baden gehen, arbeiten kommen usw.).

Comment: Wenn man das Erstglied partout als deverbales Substantiv interpretieren will, wie der Anfrager vorschlägt, schreibt man es gleichwohl getrennt, zusätzlich aber groß (§ 33 E), also beispielsweise Lesen lernen, analog zu Acht geben, Marathon laufen, Staub saugen usw."

Answer (score 4):

Until [1996](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_orthography_reform_of_1996), [spazierengehen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spazierengehen) was a separable verb, now it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse *[spazieren gehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spazieren_gehen)* with *[das Spazierengehen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Spazierengehen)*. The former is not a separable verb, it does not consist of a lexical core and a separable particle, but of two distinct verbs that together form a new expression.

Comment: Muss der erste Teil beim ersten Fall nicht großgeschrieben werden? `Spazieren gehen, Bummeln gehen, Einkaufen gehen`? M.E. ist nur in Zusammenschreibung Kleinschreibung erlaubt. `spazierengehen, bummelngehen, einkaufengehen`. Ich bin aber mit alter Schreibung groß geworden und bin in Sprachtheorie nicht bewandert und hänge noch oft der alten Schreibung an. Schwierig finde ich Redwendungen: `Mit dieser Neuerung werdet ihr badengehen` finde ich einleuchtender als `Mit dieser Neuerung werdet ihr Baden gehen.`...

Comment: ... Aber man kann natürlich trennen, was mich wiederum verunsichert: `Mit dem Vorschlag ging er Baden` oder `Mit dem Vorschlag ging er baden`? Da ist es eine feste Wendung, im Ggs. zum `Mit dem prallen Portemonaie ging er Bummeln.`

Comment: Zitat §39 (4) "Verbindungen mit einem verbalen ersten Bestandteil.
Verbindungen aus zwei Verben werden getrennt geschrieben, zum
Beispiel:
laufen lernen, arbeiten kommen, baden gehen, lesen üben" 
Siehe auch die Diskussion unter der Antwort von Björn Friedrich :) Wir sind uns uneins darüber, ob das Zusammenschreiben hier pberhaupt erlaubt ist.