# "So macht Lesen lernen Spaß"?

Tags: spelling

Eine Ravensburger Kinder-Zeitschrift hat (hatte?) den Titel "Leserabe: So macht Lesen lernen Spaß!"

[image]

Meiner Meinung nach ist das falsch. Richtig wäre

- So macht Lesenlernen Spaß!

wegen §36(2), mehrteilige Substantivierungen: das Holzholen, das Inkraftreten.
Was macht Spaß? Das Lesenlernen. Das Lernen.

Eine andere mögliche Formulierung wäre,

- So macht es Spaß, lesen zu lernen.
- So macht es Spaß, Lesen zu lernen.

Hier sehe ich beide Möglichkeiten, je nachdem ob man *lernt zu lesen* oder ob man *das Lesen lernt*. Zusammenschreibung wäre falsch, denn man kann "das Lesen lernen", d.h. das Substantiv hat seine eigenständige Form nicht verloren und fällt deshalb nicht unter §34(3) (kopfstehen, teilnehmen).

Richtig?

Comment: Schreibt man nach deiner Interpretation der Regeln dann auch "So macht *Autofahrenlernen* Spaß"?

Comment: §36 (2) besagt aber doch "Zusammen- wie auch getrennt geschrieben werden *kann* ...", von daher sehe ich nicht, wie man darauf eine Aussage stützen kann, dass eine Getrenntschreibung falsch ist.

Comment: Sorry, ich meinte §37(2), nicht §36(2). (Edit geht momentan nicht.) // Klar. Das Holzholen, das Bahnfahren, das Auf-die-lange-Bank-Schieben, das Immer-recht-Haben. Warum nicht das Auto-fahren-Lernen? // (Sorry, wir haben uns mit mehreren Accounts verhakt.)

Comment: @tofro   Auf jeden Fall heißt es *So macht Fiesekommentareschreiben Spaß*.

Comment: Auf jeden Fall schreibt man Ratte mit doppel-T, nicht mit B. :)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Es heißt *das Fiese-Kommentare-Schreiben*, wegen §43 oder würdest Du sagen, das ist noch eine "übersichtliche Zusammensetzung"?

Answer (score 4):

Dieses Thema wurde gerade gestern [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/sie-traf-ihn-als-sie-am-ufer-entlang-spazieren-ging) ausgiebig diskutiert, ohne zu einer eindeutigen Antwort zu kommen. Daraufhin habe ich mich erkundigt und eine Aussage von Prof. Bär, dem Leiter der Vechtaer Sprachauskunft erhalten, die deine Frage wohl auch direkt beantwortet:

> [...] dass § 34 (3) nicht deverbale Substantivierungen im Blick hat, sondern primäre Substantive. Also nicht Beispiele wie lesenlernen (weil ≠ das Lesen lernen), sondern kopfstehen, teilhaben, standhalten, nottun usw. Bei verbalem Erstglied greift § 34 (4); diese Wörter werden getrennt geschrieben (laufen lernen, baden gehen, arbeiten kommen usw.). Wenn man das Erstglied partout als deverbales Substantiv interpretieren will, wie der Anfrager vorschlägt, schreibt man es gleichwohl getrennt, zusätzlich aber groß (§ 33 E), also beispielsweise Lesen lernen, analog zu Acht geben, Marathon laufen, Staub saugen usw."

Comment: Den Unterschied zwischen "teilhaben" und "lesen lernen" sehe ich auch. Was soll "lesenlernen (weil ≠ das Lesen lernen)" bedeuten? Der letzte Satz ist mir zu pauschaul. Wenn man es als Substantiv ansieht, dann kommt es trotzdem auf den Satz an, ob man zusammen oder getrennt schreibt. "Ich gehe Holz holen" vs. "Das Holzholen macht mir Spaß".

Comment: Es soll sicher bedeuten, dass es "lesenlernen" als Verb nicht gibt.
Deine genannten Beispiele sind ja etwas ganz anderes. Der letzte Satz bezieht sich ja auf deverbale Substantive, nicht auf Substantive wie "Holz". Die Verknüpfung von "gewöhnlichen" Substantiven ist ja in § 34 (3) eindeutig definiert.

Comment: Ich verstehe Deine Antwort nur bezugnehmend auf den letzten Gedanken. wie stehst Du zu "So macht Lesen lernen Spaß!"? Falsch?

Comment: Das scheint mir auch etwas zufällig gewählt. Wenn man aber als gesetzt annimmt, dass "lesenlernen" nicht existiert (mit obiger Begründung), dann könnte man trotzdem annehmen, dass die getrennt geschriebene Form "Lesen lernen" neben "lesen lernen" existiert, wenn man eindeutig das Substantiv "Lesen" verwenden will.

Comment: Aber @RoyPJ, so weit ich mich erinnere, war einer der Gründe für die Reform, solche Unterschiede loszuwerden: also eben nicht _autofahren_ versus _Lesen lernen_, sondern _autofahren_ und _lesenlernen_, sofern _(das) Lesen_ gemeint ist, das heißt, eine einzige Regel für das Muster _Substantiv + Verb_. Zudem kann man Regeln für eine bestimmte Wortart (Substantive) nicht einschränken, indem man sagt, sie meine ja eigentlich nur bestimmte Substantive. Sonst könnte man genauso gut behaupten, eine bestimmte Regel für Verben meine ja eigentlich nur die reflexiven Verben.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ich möchte gar keine Aussage darüber machen, ob ich es als sinnvoll erachte, wie es gehandhabt wird. Die Alternative aus deiner Antwort im anderen Post empfand ich auch nicht als befriedigend. Aber die Kompetenz der Vechtaer Sprachauskunft setze ich über die unsere und nehme somit deren Aussagen als *wahr* hin.